# How can I search an xml file for a value with a VB Script and then output to a central location if i found that value?

Tags: xml, vbscript

Pretty much.. we have a value in an XML file that is breaking things.  I need to search over 400 computers to see if the value is in the XML file.

I created a VB script to get to the file in question but i don't know the command to search for the value within an xml and report back that the client has the value.

I don't want to change the value yet, just want to see what's out there.

linux is much easier bc i can just use a GREP command on a file and use a shell script.

any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: commands that may be available on your Windows system which have limited grep-like functionality are [`find`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx) and [`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx). They can be used in a batch file in a similar way to your linux shell script

Comment: i'm going to try this... findstr seems to be an easier way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If a simple substring search is all you want,

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set src = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)
fileBody = src.readall
src.close()
if(InStr(fileBody,"value to search") > 0) Then
Msgbox "Found!";
End If
```

For a RegExp search , instead of `InStr` use `RegExp` ([helpful link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_regexp.php))

Comment: As string positions start at 1 in VBScript, you should test for "> 0" instead of ">=0".

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, Whoops! Fixed. I blame Java.

Comment: @st0le @Ekkehard.Horner Thanks for your feedback but i'm still having a problem.  Its a compilation error. on this line `if (InStr(fileBody,""value="Y" id="TOOLS_USE_SOFTRENDER"")  > 0) Then `

Comment: @user1101105, You'll have to escape those double quotes...try this, `"value=" & chr(34) & "Y" & chr(34) &  " id="& chr(34) & "TOOLS_USE_SOFTRENDER"& chr(34)` or `"value=""Y"" id=""TOOLS_USE_SOFTRENDER"""`